# android : parsing nested xml with same node name in different levels

Tags: android, xml-parsing

in the xml file , there are nodes with same name in different levels. How can i distinguish based on the leve or parent

```
<account email="psuraj@isaacdanielgroup.com" >

<contacts>

    <contact>
        <id>
        0
        </id>
    </contact>
    <contact>
        <id>
         1
        </id>
    </contact>
    <contact>
        <id>
         2
        </id>
    </contact>
</contacts>

<groups>

    <group>

        <groupname>
         xyz

        </groupname>

        <members>

            <contact>

                <id>
                 7

                </id>
            </contact>

            <contact>

                <id>
                 8
                </id>
            </contact>
        </members>
    </group>
</groups>
```

here i have contact under contacts as well as under groups ->group->memebers 
I need to distinguish between them
if i try

```
doc.getElementsByTagName("contact");
```

it will return all the contact nodes in all levels.
This is not what is required. I need to contact unders contacts separate and under memebers separate.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

using DOM XML technology you can extract NodeSet by mean of XPATHExpression:

```
   String path = "//account/groups/group/members/contact";
   XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
    XPathExpression expr1;
    try {
        expr1 = xpath.compile(path);
        return (NodeList)expr1.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
    } catch (XPathExpressionException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
```

this will return only contact inside groups